# Short circuits and simplified circuit diagrams

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, short-circuit

[image]

I see that the 30F capacitor is shorted because both terminals are connected to the same node, but I'm having trouble seeing why the two circuits are equivalent. Is it something to do with KVL and current?

Comment: there's something haging off the right side of the image. What's that? Because the parts you show simply are *not* equivalent, as you correctly observed.

Comment: There isn't anything hanging off it. It's just an extended wire but there are no circuit elements attached. But the circuit equivalence is wrong because when finding equivalent capacitance, we are allowed to ignore the 30F capacitor right?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you! Helped clear a lot of confusion

Comment: the question here is why you have less-than-perfect teaching material (I mean, it's not "breaking" the material, but who draws polarized capacitors this asymmetrically?! Someone who can't operate an electronics layout program properly!), and trust that more than your correct understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two circuits are ***not*** equivalent.

It is the 30F capacitor that should be removed in the lower, equivalent circuit, *not* the short circuit. That capacitor cannot have a non-zero potential difference across it, and its presence or absence has no effect on the impedance of 0Ω between those two nodes.

Comment: The circuit is not practical right? Since it uses polarized caps, when a DC voltage is applied between terminals A and B, it could damage the caps.

Comment: @Jonathan_the_seagull (Mr. Livingstone, I presume?) The main reason this circuit is not practical is the absolutely HUGE values! 30 Farads is ridiculously large, and I can't imagine such caps would ever be configured in this way. You're right though, being polarised, there are likely to be some reverse-charged caps in there. Difficult to say at first glance.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.